# Bitmap size vs quality - for outofmemory Exception

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I tested and require clarification. 
If I load a bitmap that's high quality (let us say 4 MB 480p) but has tiny size and if load one that's huge in size (2mb 2k) but low in image quality- which one gonna cause Out of memory Exception?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you can try it for yourself and get the answer.

Usually, a very large bitmap (like 4096x4096) won't load that easy, and you would need to scale it.

Android system is pretty smart, so it wouldn't allow the bitmap of previously said size to load.

Secondly, if you will try to load heavy bitmap (like 10mb) regardless of size, if size fits in maximum size values, it will most likely caues **OutOfMemoryException.**

I would like to recommend you this official guide of scaling the Bitmaps, so I hope you and your application users would never have such problems.

[Official Android Developers Guide on scaling Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

[Cool Video from Android Perfomance Patters on scaling Bitmaps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY9aaXHx8yA)